# Android. Default text color

Tags: android, android-layout

Hallo everybody,

I'd like to use black color as default text color only in one activity.

I guess, I should use Theme and Styles, but I didn't find any good information relating to my question or to only one activity.

Is it possible to change default text color only for one activity?

If yes, could you give me an example please, how to do this?

Mur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `android:theme` tag to just an activity:

```
<activity
  android:name=".SomeActivity"
  android:theme="@style/Theme.ForSomeActivity"
/>
```